# Capturing uppercase words in text with regex

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to find words that are in uppercase in a given piece of text. The words must be one after the other to be considered and they must be at least 4 of them.

I have a "almost" working code but it captures much more: `[A-Z]*(?: +[A-Z]*){4,}`. The capture group also includes spaces at the start or the end of those words (like a boundary).

I have a playground if you want to test it out: https://regex101.com/r/BmXHFP/2

Is there a way to make the regex in example capture only the words in the first sentence? The language I'm using is `Go` and it has no look-behind/ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex, you just need to change the second `*` for a `+`:

```
[A-Z]*(?: +[A-Z]+){4,}
```

#### Explanation

While using `(?: +[A-Z]*)`, you are matchin "*a space followed by 0+ letters*". So you are matching spaces. When replacing the `*` by a `+`, you matches spaces if there are uppercase after.

### [Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BmXHFP/4)

Comment: Good catch. Any way I can make sure the match starts with a letter and not with a space?

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea Of course, change the first `*` to a `+` as well! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `*`s by `+`s, and your regex only matches the words in the first sentence.

`.*` also matches the empty string. Looking at you regex and ignoring both `[A-Z]*`, all that remains is a sequence of spaces. Using `+` makes sure that there is at least one uppercase char between every now and then.

Answer (score 1):

You had to mark at least 1 upper case as `[A-Z]*(?: +[A-Z]+){4,}` see updated [regex](https://regex101.com/r/BmXHFP/3).

A better Regex will allow non spaces as `[A-Z]*(?: *[A-Z]+){4,}`.see better [regex](https://regex101.com/r/BmXHFP/5)

`*` After  will indicate to allow at least upper case even without spaces.